# row_number() not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.no_ ORDER BY app.beacon, l.beacon) AS seqnum 
     FROM
         loan l
     LEFT JOIN 
         cust c ON c.rowno = l.rowno_custloan_cust
     LEFT JOIN 
         Applicant a ON a.CIFId = c.rowno
     LEFT JOIN 
         Application app ON app.ApplicantId = a.ApplicantId 
    ) loan l
LEFT JOIN 
    cust c ON c.rowno = l.rowno_custloan_cust
LEFT JOIN 
    Applicant a ON a.CIFId = c.rowno
LEFT JOIN 
    Application app ON app.ApplicantId = a.ApplicantId
WHERE 
    l.code IN ('DM', 'MF', 'DV', 'MC', 'MO', 'MC','MF','HR','OF','ML','VR','RV','S1','11','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6','y7','y8','y9')
    AND seqnum = 1
ORDER BY
    l.rowno
```

When I run this, I get an error

> Incorrect Syntax Near 'l'

which is the `loan l` in my 2nd `FROM`.

I'm new to `row_number()` and I must just be missing something. If you know an easier way to get the `row_number()` and select row # 1 for each c.no_ that would be helpful too

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Look at the alias for your subquery. It is "loan l". If you want that as your alias (not what I would recommend) you need to use [loan l].

Comment: Just a typo, you can't use 2 aliases on the derived table.  Remove the word `loan` and it should work...

Comment: You're giving your subquery 2 aliases `loan` and `l`. that's not how SQL works. you can only give it 1.

Comment: I don't think you need to do those joins in both the outer query and the subquery.

Comment: so should my subquery have aliases or the main query? loan is the table name, l is the alias

Comment: It is time to stop and think a bit. What is your goal? The use of left joins seems incorrect given the table names involved. How can a loan not be associated with a customer? Or an applicant? Or an application? The use of distinct is also highly suspicious. The use of rowno in the order by clause seems wrong - your rownumber function has the alias seqnum. At the very least, you should start over and start building and testing your query piece-by-piece.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are using the Alias name wrongly. The alias name for the first `SELECT` statement is used as `) loan l`, here `loan` is the alias name so `l` is not recognized and it throws error.

I have renamed the `loan l` to `AliasLoan` and changed its relevant places:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.no_ ORDER BY app.beacon, l.beacon) AS seqnum
    FROM loan l
    LEFT JOIN cust c ON c.rowno = l.rowno_custloan_cust
    LEFT JOIN Applicant a ON a.CIFId = c.rowno
    LEFT JOIN Application app ON app.ApplicantId = a.ApplicantId
    ) AliasLoan
LEFT JOIN cust c ON c.rowno = AliasLoan.rowno_custloan_cust
LEFT JOIN Applicant a ON a.CIFId = c.rowno
LEFT JOIN [Application] app ON app.ApplicantId = a.ApplicantId
WHERE AliasLoan.code IN ('DM', 'MF', 'DV', 'MC', 'MO', 'MC','MF','HR','OF','ML','VR','RV','S1','11','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6','y7','y8','y9')
    AND AliasLoan.seqnum = 1
ORDER BY AliasLoan.rowno
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want this?

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT l.*, c.*, a.*, app.*
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.no_ ORDER BY app.beacon, l.beacon) AS seqnum 
      FROM loan l LEFT JOIN 
           cust c
           ON c.rowno = l.rowno_custloan_cust LEFT JOIN 
           Applicant a
           ON a.CIFId = c.rowno LEFT JOIN
           Application app
           ON app.ApplicantId = a.ApplicantId 
      WHERE l.code IN ('DM', 'MF', 'DV', 'MC', 'MO', 'MC','MF','HR','OF','ML','VR','RV','S1','11','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6','y7','y8','y9')
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY seqnum;
```